# Отключение звукового оповещения

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, аудио

Создал приложение, где используются звуковые оповещения.
Такой код:

```
//Добавляю в body аудио файл
$('<audio id="notify"><source src="notify.ogg" type="audio/ogg"><source src="notify.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"><source src="notify.wav" type="audio/wav"></audio>').appendTo('body');
```

И в функциях вызываю так:

```
$('#notify')[0].play();
```

как создать отключение звука на сайте, а именно аудио с id **#notify** через checkbox ?

Мой неправильный код:

```
$("#mute").click(function () {
    $(function(){
        if ($("#mute").is(":checked")) {
            $("#notify").prop('muted', true);
        } else {
            $("#notify").prop('muted', false);
        }
    });
});
```

**#mute** - это id checkbox'а

Помогите решить задачу, пожалуйста.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы перепутали назначение функций:

Функция

```
$(function(){
   ....
});
```

будет вызвана по окончанию загрузки **DOM**.

---

Функция

```
$("#mute").click(function () {
   ....
});
```

поставит обработчик события `click` на элемент `#mute`. Причем обработчик не поставится на элемент, пока DOM не будет загружен, только потому, что этого элемента еще как бы нет в дереве `DOM`.

Поэтому получается:

```
$(function(){
    $("#mute").click(function () {
        if ($("#mute").is(":checked")) {
            $("#notify").prop('muted', true);
        } else {
            $("#notify").prop('muted', false);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Благодарю за внимание! Вы помогли.